# Два Get запроса c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть ли возможность сделать два Get запроса к одному API ? Например функция1 вернет число 1, функция2 вернет число 2.
Требуется для получение двух разных ответов с двух разных функций в одном контроллере. Оба Get запроса. Как такая вещь реализуется?

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос добавив больше информации, а конкретней чего Вы добиваетесь, какова цель, какая проблема...

Comment: Да, есть. Только вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: вопрос в реализации

Comment: как вариант разные параметры....или какой нибудь один параметр, который решит что возращать

Comment: а обходных путей нет? обращение чисто к функции

Comment: Например, так: `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`, тогда при обращении надо указать нужный action (наименование метода)

Comment: Дополнительный параметр можно передавать в пути: `?param=1` или в каком-нибудь хедере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в контроллере у методов есть атрибут, который предписывает схему, т.е httpGet,httpPost, ты же можешь сделать например

```
[HttpGet("method1")]
public IActionResult Method1()
{
 return Ok("value 1");
}

[HttpGet("method2")]
public IActionResult Method2()
{
 return Ok("value 2");
}
```

И пожалуйста, обращайся к своему приложению : localhost:9200/method1 или localhost:9200/method2

Ну и если у контроллера был route, то естественно его в url'e используй.